# what is directory folder for aircrack-ng?

Tags: directory, aircrack-ng, kali

I just uninstall aircrack-ng from my computer then install it again but now I want to know where can I put it , which folder I should put aircrack-ng in ?

Comment: Ehm. you installed from source?

Answer (score 3):

When you install from the official repositories it is installed in the places `apt-get` installs software. So all over the place and generally you do not get to pick the place where to install it. If the software has a 'user' component, that will be installed inside your `/home/$USER/`, either in a normal or hidden directory.

If you install from source you can to pick a diretory yourself, either by extracting the download or you get asked by the installer. The general rule is: install in `/opt/`.

And a method would be to install in `/opt/{software-name-with-version-number}/`. That way you can install several versions next to each other. And you can then symlimk to `/opt/{software}/` and put that inside your PATH or symlink a binairy inside a directory in your PATH to that executable. If you want to switch versions you switch the symlink to that version.